# Gerar imagem usando o PHP para diretório

Tags: php, html, imagem

Desculpe sé ficou muito estranha a pergunta , eu tenho um sistema que quando o upload do usuário não possui imagem ele coloca no img seguinte diretório:

```
/xxxx/estatico/comuns/sem_imagem/
```

Minha ideia era gerar um index.php nesse diretório que gerasse a imagem , é correto este método ou utilizaria recursos do servidor em vão? 
Eu tenho uma média de 2000 acessos por dia.

Comment: sua pergunta ficou  sem contexto, vc tem um sistema de  upload, a onde o se o usuário não enviar a imagem, ele vai colocar sem imagem  correto?
mas  no  caso todo upload cria um diretorio no  seu servidor ?
e você que colocar um arquivo index.php para criar uma copia de uma imagem  padrão para esse diretorio ? 

poderia expecificar melhor a sua duvida assim poderemos ajuda-lo

Comment: Desculpe amigo , é o seguinte.
Eu tenho um upload certo , nesse upload eu tenho alguns dados que o usuário deve inserir , nesse caso  nem todos são obrigatorio como a imagem , assim toda vez que não existe uma imagem o sistema coloca no src do img esse diretório estático .
Eu gostaria de saber sé colocar um index.php ali é a maneira correta de gerar uma imagem pra ficar no lugar , entende?

Comment: Certo agora compreendi, vou postar uma resposta

Comment: Bom no caso vc não precisa criar uma imagem  toda vez que o usário n enviar aimagem  e  nem  apotar para varios diretoriosvasta apenas verificar se aimagem foi  enviada caso contrario apota a imagem para outro diretorio fixo

Comment: é porque isso é uma configuração padrão do sistema e ja existem muitos uploads assim , teria como eu fazer assim?

Answer (score 1):

Aqui vai um exemplo bem generico do que vc deseja fazer

Bom você pode criar uma função

Suponhamos que vc está recebendo seus dados do upload via $_POST

```
function QualImagemUsar(){
   if(isset($_POST['variaveldaImage']){
        $caminhoDaImagem = "pasta/imagensUsuarios/iamgemQueUsarioEnviouEVcSalvou.jpg";
   }else{
        $caminhoDaImagem = "pasta/imagensUsuarios/imagemGenerica.jpg";
   }
   return $caminhoDaImagem ;
}
```

No seu html

```
<img src="<?php echo QualImagemUsar(); ?>">
```

Creio que seja o que deseja uma função que veirifica se a imagem  foi  enviada
ou caso deseje verificar se existe a imagem  no  diretorio utilize
o `if(file_exists("diretori/arquivo.jpg")`